# Failing to catch exception thrown by "pure" function

Tags: haskell, exception

I'm trying to catch a custom exception thrown by "pure" code.  I don't understand the behavior of my program.

I'm using GHC 8.6.3.  Here's my code:

```hs
import Control.Exception

newtype Problem = Problem String deriving Show

instance Exception Problem

foo :: Int -> Int
foo n = n + (throw $ Problem "Whoops")

baz :: IO Int
baz =
  return (foo 1)
  `catch` \(Problem _) -> return 100

main = do
  n <- baz
  print n
  `catch` \(Problem msg) -> putStrLn msg
```

I expect the exception to be caught by the first handler, and for the program to print "100".  Instead it gets caught by the second handler and prints "Whoops".

Why is the exception being caught in `main` and not in `baz`?  How can I catch the exception in `baz`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to laziness, `foo 1` doesn't get executed until you actually attempt to print the value of `n`. Essentially, `n` is bound to the unevaluated thunk `foo 1`, not the result of `foo 1`.

A rather clumsy way to force `baz` to handle the exception is to use `seq`; there is almost certainly a more elegant solution.

```
baz = let result = foo 1
      in seq result (return result) `catch` \(Problem msg) -> return 100
```

And, thanks to @Alec, that more elegant solution is to simply replace `return` with `Control.Exception.evaluate` in your original function.

```
baz :: IO Int
baz =
  evaluate (foo 1)
  `catch` \(Problem _) -> return 100
```

Comment: `seq result (return result)` has a handy (slightly more efficient) function for it: `evaluate`. Plus, no need for a let binding! ```evaluate (foo 1) `catch` \(Problem msg) -> putStrLn msg```

Comment: `s/almost//`. :)

Comment: Oops! I meant: ```baz = evaluate (foo 1) `catch` \(Problem msg) -> return 100```. I got thrown off by your `catch` body (its the wrong one!).

Comment: @Alec, `evaluate` isn't more efficient; it's better behaved.

Comment: @Alec Ah, yes, that was what caused my problems trying to test `evaluate`. My test file was correct, but then I blindly copied the bad definition of `baz` in my answer. Everything's fixed now.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning in this answer that `evaluate` and `seq` will work in this particular case, but sometimes evaluating to normal form with help of `deepseq` is be necessary. Another suggestion is to not use pure `throw`